# NodeJS async API Error, when querying embedded array of models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Thanks for taking the time to read this.
I am currently getting this error in my API endpoint for node express when calling this async endpoint.

```
    (node:32308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Conversation validation failed: participants.0: Path `participants.0` is required., participants.1: Path `participants.1` is required.
    at model.Document.invalidate (D:\cliquenext\flutter\stashify\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2976:32)
    at D:\cliquenext\flutter\stashify\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2765:17
    at D:\cliquenext\flutter\stashify\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1334:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:32308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)        
(node:32308) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Basically I am trying to get a conversation, with its messages and its participants and return it.
The conversation object model is like so:

```
 const conversationSchema = new Schema(
  {
    isGroup: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
    creator: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    passwordProtected: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
    },
    participants: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
      },
    ],
    deleted: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
    ],
    seen: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
    ],
    messages: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Message',
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);
```

and this is my endpoint:

```
    exports.getMessagesFromUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // variables
    const senderId = req.userId;
    const receiverId = req.body.receiverId;

    // get users
    const sender = await User.findOne({ _id: senderId });
    const receiver = await User.findOne({ _id: receiverId });

    const ids = [senderId, receiverId];

    // look for an existing conversation between two users
    // where the participants include both users
    // where the conversation is a single conversation
    // that the sender hasn't deleted
    // if sender chooses to send a message, any undeleted conversations will be resurrected

    let conversation = await Conversation.findOne({
      isGroup: false,
      participants: {
        $all: ids,
      },
    })
      .select('participants deleted seen messages')
      .populate({ path: 'messages', select: 'sender message deleted seen createdAt' })
      .populate({ path: 'participants', select: '_id' })
      .populate({ path: 'participants', select: 'nickname' });

    if (conversation) {
      // conversation exists

      let senderBlocked = false;
      let receiverBlocked = false;
      let conversationDeleted = false;
      let filter;
      // check if sender has blocked the receiver
      filter = sender.blocked.filter((u) => u._id == receiverId);
      if (filter.length > 0) {
        senderBlocked = true;
      }
      filter = null;

      // check if receiver has blocked the sender
      filter = receiver.blocked.filter((u) => u._id == senderId);
      if (filter.length > 0) {
        receiverBlocked = true;
      }
      filter = null;

      // check if sender has deleted the conversation
      filter = conversation.deleted.filter((u) => u._id == senderId);
      if (filter.length > 0) {
        conversationDeleted = true;
      }

      // get, map and return the messageSchema
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Conversations fetched successfully!',
        conversation: conversation,
        senderBlocked: senderBlocked,
        receiverBlocked: receiverBlocked,
        conversationDeleted: conversationDeleted,
      });
    } else {
      // if conversation does not exist, return empty array
      // conversations will be created upon initial message between users

      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'No Conversations Yet.',
        conversation: [],
        senderBlocked: false,
        receiverBlocked: false,
        conversationDeleted: false,
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    e.statusCode = 500;
    next(e);
  }
};
```

I was able to determine the error was throwing inside this endpoint but couldn't for the life of me figure out why. I have added a try, catch and next block. Made sure I had the appropriate awaits in order, etc. My only guess here is the mongoose query of populate and select is wrong somehow? What do you think I am doing wrong here? Please and thank you.

Comment: I think you are seeing this message from other route. The reason is the message is about required fields, specifically the "participants" field. Somewhere, you save the Model without that field, that's what the error about. Your current provided code only has Find function, which won't cause that error. You should check again your code-flow or provide full code

Comment: Hi jimmy! thank you, you were right!

There was another socket route I was emitting to.
I basically added the mistake in my answer

Answer (score 1):

As jimmy pointed out, the problem wasn't there. it was in another socket route where I was trying to save new conversations if they didnt exist.

So I had something like:

```
   socket.on('join-inbox-rooms', async (data) => {
  // decode json string
  const decodedData = await JSON.parse(data);
  // get conversation
  let conversation = await Conversation.findOne({
    isGroup: false,
    participants: {
      $all: [decodedData.senderId, decodedData.receiverId],
    },
  });

  if (!conversation) {
    conversation = new Conversation({
      isGroup: false,
      creator: decodedData.senderId,
      passwordProtected: false,
      paassword: null,
      participants: [
        decodedData.senderId,
        decodedData.receiverId,
      ],
      deleted: [],
      seen: [],
      messages: [],
    });
    await conversation.save();
  }
```

Now I was getting the ids from the front end as strings. They should be mongo objects.

I ended up fixing it like so:

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

  if (!conversation) {
    conversation = new Conversation({
      isGroup: false,
      creator: decodedData.senderId,
      passwordProtected: false,
      paassword: null,
      participants: [
        ObjectId(decodedData.senderId),
        ObjectId(decodedData.receiverId),
      ],
      deleted: [],
      seen: [],
      messages: [],
    });
    await conversation.save();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. As you are receiving ids from user-input, you can also verify the ids by using ObjectId.isValid function

Comment: the ids were originally from mongodb database, but get passed back from the client every so often as a string.